# Hot water trickles, but cold water fine from same inlet on faucet

Tags: kitchens, plumbing-fixture

This one is baffling me so I'll try to describe it clearly. We have a single-spout, single-handle kitchen faucet.

The hot water pressure is just north of a trickle, but only just. The cold water pressure is fine. The faucet itself is tough to disassemble, so to test, I swapped the inlet hoses from hot on the left to hot on the right, same with cold. In this opposite configuration, the water pressures ON BOTH sides are strong and fine. Water gets hot quickly as expected.

Swapping back to the appropriate configuration of hot on the left cold on the right results in hot water trickling while cold water is strong.

What can be wrong or what can I test?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a malfunctioning anti-scald mechanism.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, and didn't know that thing existed. After about 10 minutes of research though, it looks like an anti-scald mechanism just physically limits the mix of hot and cold water to the tap? If so, then I don't think it can be the cause because when I hook up the cold water to the hot water side, I get full pressure. 

Am I understanding an anti-scald mechanism correctly?

Comment: The anti-scald mechanism is built into the left side of he faucet and only reacts to hot water